# MySQL 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 Install - How to get it working

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

Anyone know why when I grab the file:

Mac OS X 10.5 (x86_64)

from:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg

and install via the PKG installer, I am getting a 32bit install (or so says the Preference Pane)?

UPDATE: it's not the 32bitness whichi si in question - that was a PrefPane problem.  Now, the mysql.sock isn't getting created.  Did a "find" on the HDD and can't find it.  Not in /var or /tmp.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your system 64 bit capable? Are you using snow leopard?

Comment: Yes, I am running snow leopard, and have solved the problem of the Pref Pane - pref pane says 32 bit.

My issue now is that mysql.sock never gets created and is nowhere to be found.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

What does Activity Monitor show? Mine's been showing as a 64 bit app since installing it on Leopard, even though the preference pane has it listed as 32 bit.

Comment: With the edit to the question my answer is no longer relevant. However, the modified question is ringing some belles in my head. I'm pretty sure I had the same problem way back but can't recall what I did to fix it. FWIW, I also don't have mysql.sock on my Mac, even though mysqld is running and working properly.

Comment: how did you get MySQL to start?  Mine fails because a connection cannot be made to mysql.sock

Comment: If I remember or find the reference that I used I'll certainly let you know but that was a while back and my memory is quite a bit less than perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The preference pane is 32bit, the actual MySQL software is 64bit. It's annoying because the build is not specifically for 10.6 but is intended for 10.4 and 10.5. I could only get MySQL started by installing mysql-5.4.1-beta-osx10.5-x86_64 instead of the 5.1 non-beta.

Answer (score 0):

Does running `touch /tmp/mysql.sock` allow it to start?

Answer (score 0):

The socket file `mysql.sock` is created when you start up `mysqld`... `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`. The socket file should be created in the `/tmp/` directory by default.

I had the same issue and more... the way I got rid of the socket problem was by renaming my config file `/etc/my.cnf` so that it won't be loaded by MySQL. My config file is simple but if yours is complicated, try commenting out the lines that look like `socket = /some_path/`.

Hope that helps.